# Android firebase Google sign failing on Production but working on signed apk

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am working on an app that I have integrated Google firebase sign in.

On my firebase console, I have two SHA-1 certificate fingerprints:

1. Debug key
2. Key Generated by keytool

I synched google.services.json  with the app and generated a signed apk using Android studio.

Also in my play store console, App signing is enabled.

The problem is that when I use the app downloaded from play store, sign in fails. It only works with the release I have on my computer.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Thanks Nick Fortescue, add the App Signing certs to my firebase console solved the issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the key provided by Google Play app signing in your firebase console.

It's described [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) "Register your app signing key with API providers".

"To find the certificate of the key Google uses to re-sign your APK for delivery:

- Sign in to your Play Console.
- Select an app.
- On the left menu, click Release management > App signing.
  From this page, you can copy the most common fingerprints (MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256) of your app signing certificate. If the API provider requires a different type of fingerprint, you can also download the original certificate in DER format and run it through the transformation tools that the API provider requires."

Comment: With the current version of the Play Console go to Release/Setup/App Integrity